# C# Anonymous Functions Inside WebAPI Function?

Tags: c#, function, events, asp.net-web-api, delegates

I have a Web API function that is called from somewhere, but in it, I have a service that requires delegates, specifically for complete and error (though they're examples.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MyApiFuncAsync()
{
      SomeService s = new Service();

      HttpResponseMessage responseMessage;

      EventHandler completeEventHandler = (info) => {
          responseMessage = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK); 
      };

      EventHandler errorEventHandler = (error) =>{
          responseMessage = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
      };


      s.Complete += completeEventHandler;

      s.Error +=  errorEventHandler;

      try
      {
           await s.PerformService();
      }
      finally
      {
           s.Complete -= completeEventHandler;
           s.Error -= errorEventHandler;
      }

      return responseMessage;
}
```

I haven't done this before, and it might work differently than if my outer function is in a desktop/console application.

I understand that the line `await s.PerformService()` will sit there until either one of those event handlers is fired. So by then, `responseMessage` would've been already set to the correct response. I'm thinking, though, that I might end up returning null because it's probably not the same variable that I'm trying to set inside those event handlers.

How should I restructure this function?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct provided that HttpResponseMessage is a class and not a struct. Lambdas will capture reference types by reference and value types by value. Once captured by reference, it will write to the exact same variable you are returning.

One caveat to be aware of is if you are doing this inside of a for loop and you capture the loop variable by reference, then if the lambda executes after the loop is finished (which is usually the case) it will read the final value from the loop variable.

A lambda together with its captured variables is called a closure if you'd like to look it up for more information;